# Parse REST API, Validate User session

Tags: java, rest, session, token

I am using Parse REST API for a game, altough there are java libraries for Parse I would like to handle the transfer protocolls my self using java.net for learning purposes. Please look away from things like, why dont I use Apache HttpClient.

### Following the Parse REST API Guide

**Here is what I am trying to achive:**

- [Signup](https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide#users-signing-up)
- User [Login](https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide#users-logging-in)
- [validating session tokens / Retriving current user](https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide#users-validating-session-tokens-retrieving-current-user)

---

The first two steps works just fine, the former using POST request method and the latter using GET with some paramaters.

Keeping the [Request and Response](https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide#quick-reference-request-format) format in mind I also provide the *Application-ID* and the *REST-API-Key* which are the appropriate request headers needed.

Now, for the third step using GET request with no paramaters, but with an additional header, the API expects there to be a *Session-Token* provided.

---

### Code

```
private static void validateSessionToken(String token) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Token: " + token);

    URL url = new URL("https://api.parse.com/1/users/me");
    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    con.setRequestProperty("X-Parse-Application-Id", "xxxxxxx");
    con.setRequestProperty("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", "xxxxxxxx");
    con.setRequestProperty("X-Parse-Session-Token", token);
    con.setRequestProperty("content-type", "application/json");

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    if(responseCode == 400) {
        System.out.println("Bad request!");
        return;
    }

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    System.out.println(response.toString());
}
```

### Outputs

```
Sending 'GET' request to URL : https://api.parse.com/1/users/me
Response Code : 400
Bad request!
```

---

### Debugging

I have been using the PARSE API CONSOLE and Chrome network debugging tool to try and see what the difference is, but cannot see any.

**From wiki:**

> *400 Bad Request* 
>   The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing)

**Some photos that may help**

[image: Console]

[image: Header]

Answer (score 0):

So when I asked my JsonObject for the session token:

```
jsonObject.get("sessionToken").toString();
```

It returned: **"r:WzB7qdmhkcW5qd2moM8gbBLDp"** in quotation, but using:

```
jsonObject.get("sessionToken").getAsString();
```

it returned: **r:WzB7qdmhkcW5qd2moM8gbBLDp**

I was so focused on the request I did not even notice...